# How do I create an array from multiple tables

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, multidimensional-array

I have 3 models: Carriers, Products, Rates.  Each Carrier `has_many :products` and each Product `has_many :rates`.  I am trying to create an html table that will loop through each product and display *only the most current rate*.  I assume I need to store this in an array (or hash?), but not quite sure how (as I am new to programming, but learning!).  Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do the model like this:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  def current_rate
    rates.order('created_at ASC').last
  end
end
```

And then this in the view:

```
<%= product.current_rate %>
```

Answer (score 1):

The most recent rate is the last rate created on your database. And if this information is true, that means a SQL query getting just one (`limit 1`) row ordered by the creation date descending (`created_at DESC`) would get the record you want. Knowing this you can create a scope in your rate model:

```
scope :current_rate, order('rates.created_at DESC').limit(1).first
# As @AntohnyAlberto said, limit would bring an array, so you may use .first on the results
# Or you can use just .first, as it would bring only the first one
scope :current_rate, order('rates.created_at DESC').first
```

And use this scope on your product loop in your view:

```
  <%= product.rate.current_rate %>
```

Comment: Using `limit`, AR will bring back a collection of models ... better use `first` instead to get an object back directly : `scope :current_rate, order('rates.created_at DESC').first`